# D3.js Trendline x-axis date

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Want to build a trendline similar to what [Mike Bostock did](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245).

There's a difference in the dataset: on the first column, mine has a number which represents the year **(2000)** and Mike has a date **(24-Apr-07)**.

The result I'm getting is the following:
[image]

**Goal:** I want the x axis to show the years.

**Problem:** For some weird reason, it's showing some other numbers.

**Action:**

*.index.html:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Plotting a Trendline with D3.js</title>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%y");

var x = d3.scaleTime()
    .rangeRound([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.ano); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.total); });

d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(d) {
  d.ano = d.ano;
  d.total = +d.total;
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.ano; }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.total; }));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
    .select(".domain")
      .remove();

  g.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    .append("text")
      .attr("fill", "#000")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", "0.71em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Numero de acidentes mortais");

  g.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
      .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
      .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      .attr("d", line);
});

</script>
```

*.data.tsv:*

```
ano total
2000    368
2001    365
2002    357
2003    312
2004    306
2005    300
2006    253
2007    276
2008    231
2009    217
2010    208
2011    196
2012    175
2013    160
```

**What can i do to solve this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your time parsing function (you should use `Y` in uppercase):

```
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y");
```

Working demo (I hardcoded tsv data to simplify example):

```js
  var dataAsTsv = `ano total
2000 368
2001 365
2002 357
2003 312
2004 306
2005 300
2006 253
2007 276
2008 231
2009 217
2010 208
2011 196
2012 175
2013 160`;

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y");

var x = d3.scaleTime()
    .rangeRound([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.ano); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.total); });

function processData(d) {
  d.ano = parseTime(d.ano);
  d.total = +d.total;
  return d;
};

var data = d3.tsvParse(dataAsTsv, processData);

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.ano; }));
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.total; }));

g.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
  .select(".domain")
  .remove();

g.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
  .append("text")
  .attr("fill", "#000")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", "0.71em")
  .attr("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Numero de acidentes mortais");

g.append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
  .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
  .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
  .attr("d", line);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.12.2/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
```